# Product and quotient in Abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

In linear algebra, for any vector space $V$ and its subspace $U$, there exists a subspace $W$ of $V$ such that $U\oplus W=V$ and $W\cong V/U$.

Does similar property hold for Abelian groups? That is, for any Abelian group $G$ and its (normal) subgroup $H$, is there a subgroup $K$ of $G$ such that $H\times K = G$ (which is sometimes written as $H\oplus K$) and $G/H \cong K$?  If not, for what kind of group does it hold? (I believe such a property does not hold for general groups.)

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you considered small examples? ($C_2\le C_4$...) What do you know about abelian groups? BTW if $H\le G$ is such that $G=H\times K$ for some $K\le G$, then we say $H$ is a direct summand of $G$, so this property has a name.

Comment: As anon suggests, $C_2\subset C_4$ provides a simple counterexample.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension